# How to change <a> tag href using php file_get_contents()

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using file_get_contents (http://example.com/books.php?id=55).
I am using search and replace function but not working.

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://example.com/category.php?c=55');
echo $homepage;

// Search replace not working
// str_replace("http://localhost/", "http://example.com/", $homepage );

?>
```

Out-Put**

```
<a class="touch" href="/textbook/book1.php">Book1</a>   
<a class="touch" href="/textbook/book2.php"> Book2</a>  
<a class="touch" href="/textbook/book3.php">Book3</a>
```

If i click on url it show `http://localhost/textbook/book1.php`. But I want `http://mysite[dot]com/link.php?id=http://example.com/textbook/book1.php`

Comment: or with REGEX:  preg_replace()

Comment: wil you give any example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php 
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://example.com/category.php?c=55');
$homepage = str_replace("textbook/", "http://localhost/xx/link.php?id=http://example.com/textbook/", $homepage );
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Comment: @john Did you tried after my post  ? what is the output now  ?

Comment: the output is http://localhost/textbook.book1.php  but i want  http://http://localhost/textbook.book1.php?id=http://example.com/textbook/book1.php

Comment: sir in source code show this url /textbook/book1.php . when i click on the link it show " localhost/textbook/book1.php "

Comment: @john glad it helped. Mark my answer. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no "localhost" in the code you parsed. So replacing "localhost" will do nothing. You just need to find the link using `href` and add your custom link. Also there might be any text "textbook" in your HTML.

Try this:

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://example.com/category.php?c=55');

$str=str_replace("href=\"", "href=\"http://newsite.com/link.php?id=http://example.com/", $homepage );

echo $str;
```